# Error in nrow[w] * ncol[w] : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, neural-network

UPDATE: This error seems a blanket statement to cover non-convergence when looking at thresholds sufficiently small, i.e. at or below the default 0.01. Increasing `threshold` and `stepmax` after monitoring `lifesign` allowed the algorithm to converge despite the hit to accuracy.

Up front, this is not a duplicate question as I have looked at all 16 of the other similar questions/answers on here and those solutions either do not exactly apply or do not solve this seemingly simple issue. The closest I found was [Getting errors while using neuralnet function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409888/getting-errors-while-using-neuralnet-function?rq=1) which has some great insights, but still left me with the same nagging error despite changing parameters in the code.

Data sample (just the first few rows):

```
X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16 X17 X18 X19 X20 X21 X22 X23 X24 X25 X26 X27 X28 X29 X30
18  1   2   4   1   5   5   5   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  2   1   1   1   5   3   5   1   2   4   1   4   4   2   1   3   1   1   2   3   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
20  2   1   1   1   3   4   4   1   2   1   1   2   2   1   1   4   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
34  1   2   2   1   2   2   2   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
25  2   1   1   2   3   5   3   1   2   2   1   4   3   1   2   1   1   1   2   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
19  1   2   1   2   2   4   2   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
21  1   2   1   2   2   4   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23  1   2   1   2   2   3   4   1   2   2   2   2   2   1   3   2   2   1   2   10  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0
19  2   1   1   2   2   2   2   1   2   2   2   1   2   1   2   1   1   1   2   14  0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0
28  2   1   1   2   1   3   3   1   2   1   0   1   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19  1   2   1   2   1   3   2   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   4   2   1   2   12  0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
18  1   2   1   1   3   4   1   1   2   2   2   1   3   2   1   1   1   1   2   17  0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
20  1   2   1   2   3   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20  1   2   1   1   1   1   3   1   2   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   2   4   16  1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1
```

Data description:
Labelled data and all numeric, so checking via `sapply(df, is.numeric)` we get `TRUE` for every variable in the data frame.

Code taken from one of the R-Blogger pages on neural nets:

```
set.seed(300)
cv.error <- NULL
k <- 10
pbar <- create_progress_bar('text')
pbar$init(k)
for(i in 1:k){
    index <- sample(1:nrow( df),round(0.9*nrow( df)))
    train.cv <- scaled[index,]
    test.cv <- scaled[-index,]
    nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train.cv,hidden=c(5,2),linear.output=T)
    pr.nn <- neuralnet::compute(nn,test.cv[,2:30])
    pr.nn <- pr.nn$net.result*(max( df$X30)-min( df$X30))+min( df$X30)
    test.cv.r <- (test.cv$X30)*(max( df$X30)-min( df$X30))+min( df$X30)
    cv.error[i] <- sum((test.cv.r - pr.nn)^2)/nrow(test.cv)
    pbar$step()
}
```

I am using variable X30 in this data frame as the labels, and I was able to get this code to converge relatively quickly, i.e. 5 minutes, when I was using heavily biased data. However, with this data set, the code does not converge because of this error:

```
Error in nrow[w] * ncol[w] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The traceback returns the following:

```
2. relist(weights, nrow.weights, ncol.weights)
1. neuralnet::compute(nn, test.cv[, 2:30])
```

I have also tried un-listing and reassembling the data frame as numeric just in case something went awry initially, but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: @Renu, per my first statement I already looked at that...especially since it literally has the same title. Also, if you look at that q/a you linked you'd see they didn't even find an answer but rather a nonsensical solution by commenting out possibly vital mechanics of the call.

Comment: @Roland, Thanks for marking this as a duplicate without showing where a viable answer is...because there isn't one on here. At least Renu posted one possible. Thanks...

Comment: 08walshth, you must pass to the compute() function a data frame that contains all the variables of the training data *except the target variable. However, `test.cv[, 2:30]` means you remove the first variable which is `X1`. Instead, you must remove the 30th column corresponding to `X30` - so the correct call is `neuralnet::compute(nn, test.cv[, -30])`